# API for zipping AND unzipping with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jar, zip

I am trying to find an API for JavaScript that can unzip and zip files in ZIP-style compression. I have found APIs for unzipping or zipping, but none for both.

Here's what I am trying to accomplish with this API I'm looking for: I need to pull a JAR from somewhere, add files and folders to the JAR, delete a directory from the JAR, then let the user put the completed JAR somewhere on their computer. Any ideas what I should use to do this?

Comment: Have you seen http://jszip.stuartk.co.uk/

Comment: @nikc Yeah, and I really liked its simplicity, but it didn't include a way to unzip files, or create a JSZip object from a pre-existing ZIP (which would be perfect).

Comment: Is there a problem with using two APIs?  If you can find one for each function why not just use both.

Comment: @AndrewJackman In theory, two APIs would be fine, but I can't find any two that I could use together in a such a way that my whole process could be done in one fatal swoop. For example, if I used JSUnzip ( http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=js-unzip ) to unzip the files, I don't think there's any way I could get the extracted files to JSZip ( http://jszip.stuartk.co.uk/ ) without having to make the users store the files. EDIT: Actually, I think https://github.com/arenevier/zipfile might work with JSZip the way I want, I'll have to try that later when I have more coding time...

Comment: This can be easily achieved with [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/) and its [filesystem API](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/fs-api.html). [This demo](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/demos/demo3.html) illustrates it : drop a zip in the "root" folder, modify zip structure and right-click on the "root" folder to generate the new zip file.